# Drawbacks of using extension methods instead of instance methods in C#

Tags: c#, static, extension-methods

Let's say I have a class named `Building`. This is created at the start of the program. I need to do like **hundreds** of operations on the variables of the Building class. Now I have two choice.

1.Define various classes with methods and pass the Building to them

```
class StoryService
{
    private readonly Building building;

    public StoryService(Building building)
    {
        this.building = building;
    }

    public void AddStory() {}
}
```

2.Define extension methods for the Building

```
static class StoryExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AddStory(this Building building) {}
}
```

Now in my application:

```
var building = new Building();

// Method 1
var storyService = new StoryService(building);
storyService.AddStory();


// Method 2
building.AddStory();
```

Now my question is which one of these is the way to go in terms of performance and good practice. Which one will decrease class coupling?

Comment: Extension methods cannot add properties or fields. Anyway, there is *no* "performance" impact here (extension methods are de-parsed to static methods) but there *are* type/binary compatibility and inheritance differences for *instance* methods: an instance method is *part* of a type hierarchy, an extension method is not.

Comment: It would be harder to test static method and it really depends on what you do. Personally I prefer to put some small repeating pieces of code into extension methods that look more like helpers and not business rules or manipulations

Comment: @user2864740 I don't need to add properties to `building` I just need to do operations on its fields.

Comment: Answer (and justify) this: is there a *reason* to use an Extension Method (or "a static method where the object is specified as an argument")? If the answer is no, then use a normal instance method. When an Extension Method is applicable, you'll "know" - generally they are used for "opening" external types, cross-cutting (a usually closed) single inheritance across different type unifications, or adding situation-specific support methods. Otherwise, keep it simple.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, Is using the first method (using helper classes) is wise choice or should I write all the methods (hundreds of them) that operate on Building inside the Building class?

Comment: A sane (for us mere programmers!) design should not have a hundred - much less hundreds of! - methods in a class. That sounds like it is violating SRP. My *personal* "class size limit" is approximately 1500 lines, or a few dozen methods .. tops.

Comment: @user2864740 My building class is just composed of all the data loaded. I use it to dump my data regarding the various properties of a building. like columns, beams, points, etc. Then I need to do operations on these data?

Comment: With "OO", one generally doesn't do `Building.AddBeam()`, but `Building.Beams.Add(..)`. That is, a Building "has a collection of" many Beams.

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry I'm going a little off-topic here. Then you mean that I should define Beams,Columns,... classes inside the building class, and define the relevant methods inside each of the Beams,... classes?

Comment: @Vahid Generally, yes. It's not always a strict Collection-Noun-Verb pattern but conventional/C# class design usually revolves around decomposition to an object-graph. Here is a [tongue in cheek](http://hadihariri.com/2013/11/24/refactoring-to-functionalwhy-class/) post about a programmer's adventures - not *really* relevant, but "many of us have been there, done that" ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess now I need to go do some major changes to my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never found a particularly good reason to use static extensions as doing so can (if someone else is working on the codebase) be a little bit confusing for them because there's several places to look for method declarations on a given class.

However, static extensions on things you don't own (adding a new method to string for making it title case, for instance) make a lot of sense.

So I'd say to avoid it if possible but if you feel the need to or don't have the ability to edit the class itself, then create the extension and make sure other people know about it.

The performance effect is negligible.

Comment: I can edit the Building class, since its my own program. I was wondering if I don't write extension methods, then what choices do I have? Should I write all these methods in the Building class itself? Or as I have mentioned above use helper classes and pass the building to them? In the first case, I end of with a very bulky building class!

Comment: @Vahid Again, it depends on your scenario. Try to think of your building in terms of real world. Does this operation "belong" to the building in the real world? Say moving a lift up/down would be something the building class should be responsible for. But for example adding furniture to rooms in the building - that probably should be done by some helper/service class.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski Thanks, I think I'm starting to understand this!

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski Couldn't have said it better myself!